# Finite product of powers of sine

Tags: trigonometry

I've encountered the following finite product:

$\prod_{1\leq i<N} \left(\sin(\frac{\pi i}{N})\right)^i$

Do you know if it is known?
I've looked at various trigonometric identities handbooks, and could not find this specific one. I could only find

$\prod_{1\leq i<N} \sin(\frac{\pi i}{N})=\frac{N}{2^{N-1}}$

which is also the one reported on Wikipedia.

Have a good day!

Comment: Hint: $\sin(\frac{\pi i}N)=\sin(\frac{\pi(N-i)}N)$

Comment: $\frac{N^{\frac{N}{2}}}{2^{\frac{N(N-1)}{2}}}$